# Read String from a .txt file and then convert it to integer

Tags: java

I am attempting to read some data from a text file, this goes in the format:

```
10
1
s
q
```

here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String line = null;

        int[] b= new int[10];
        int i = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\myFile.txt"));

            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {

                b[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
                i++;

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
}
```

this `b[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);` easily reads first line from the file that is '10' and same goes for the second line that is '1' but for the third line 's' compiler gives me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

I need to convert String 's' and 'H' to an integer value and then store into my array b of integer type.

Comment: what kind of integer value do you want to store the characters to? corresponding ASCII or build a hash against them?

Answer (score 4):

Check first that if string contains alphabet or numbers

```
if(line.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
    int a=(int)line.charAt(0);

else if(line.matches("[0-9]+"))
    int a=Integer.parseInt(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you have only one character:

```
char c = b[i].charAt(0);
int x = c - 48;
```

Comment: You've to subtract 48 from the character not 46 .As ASCII of 0 is 48.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your text file into byte array then convert this array into int array

```
public static void Do()
{

    try {
        InputStream in;
        in = new FileInputStream("a.txt");
        byte[] array = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(array);
        int[] array2 = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i<array.length ; i++)
        {
            array2[i] = array[i];
            System.out.println(array2[i]+"");
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

and the output will be like this

> 13
>   10
>   99
>   13
>   10
>   100
>   13
>   10
>   100
>   102
>   104
>   102
>   103
>   104
>   103
>   102
>   104

its depending in your text file characters . 
data in a.txt is (a
b
c
d
dfhfghgfh
)

but for me ,,, I will give every char an integer value then use if statment to convert char to int